# How to calculate and of measure the applied force between a motor and a flywheel

Tags: torque, force-measurement

I am making a model for a flywheel. For this model, I found a way to calculate the torque and thus eventually the velocity of the flywheel. The flywheel itself will be floating due to magnetic bearings. Against the flywheel at the side the electrical motor will be placed. The flywheel itself will be horizontally placed. For the torque, I still need the applied pressure of the motor on the flywheel. Can I calculate this if I know the output torque of the motor. If so how would one do that?

For reference see this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/729552/how-to-calculate-the-friction-between-an-electric-motor-and-a-flywheel . I do understand this calculation but don't how to get the applied pressure that was mentioned.

In the picture the thing at the side will be the casing for the motor and the black circle in the middle is the floating flywheel.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Or just use a torque transducer instead of mucking around with pressure, friction, and all that junk.

Comment: How do you plan to achieve the required contact pressure with the design?

Comment: @TomášLétal I don't really understand your question. The motor itself will be mounted and can therefore not move. I then assume that the constant pressure is dependent on the torque of the motor.

Comment: @Jarno I don't see how contact pressure between the motor and the flywheel (it that's the pressure we are talking about) would be dependent on the torque with the design in the picture. It could be dependent on rpm, since both the motor and the flywheel will expand a little bit.

Comment: @Jarno My previous comment was for situation when you actually run the machine. However, if we are talking about the design phase, there could be a dependence of the minimum contact pressure on the torque so there would be no slip. From the diameters of both disks, their angular momenta and friction coefficient, you should be able to establish this minimum required pressure. And then implement it into your design.